# Are there any other examples of simple not absolutely simple lie algebra besides $so(3,1)$?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, simple-lie-algebras

I just learned the distinction between simple and absolutely simple Lie algebras and was wondering if there are other well known examples other than the Lorentz algebra.

Comment: Every complex simple Lie algebra viewed as a real Lie algebra is simple but not absolutely simple of which $\mathfrak{so}(3,1) \cong \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ is an example.

Comment: In fact, if I am reading Torsten's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3068134/existence-of-a-non-essentially-real-ideal-in-a-semisimple-lie-algebra) correctly, then these are the only examples.

Comment: @Callum I can see from the answer linked there are no other compact example, I'm not so sure about non-compact.

Comment: Well a complex Lie algebra certainly isn't compact viewed as a real Lie algebra. Indeed it won't be split either, although it will be quasi-split. The linked answer claims that there are **no** other examples besides these complex Lie algebras viewed as real Lie algebras.

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Just to get this off the "unanswered" list:

If $\mathfrak h$ is a simple real Lie algebra that is *not* absolutely simple (i.e. the complexification $\mathbb C \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathfrak h$ is *not* simple), then $\mathfrak h$ is the scalar restriction of a complex simple Lie algebra, i.e. there exists a *complex* simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ such that $\mathfrak h \simeq Res_{\mathbb C|\mathbb R} \mathfrak g$ as *real* Lie algebras -- where the admittedly cumbersome notation $Res_{\mathbb C|\mathbb R}$ means scalar restriction i.e. forgetting the complex structure i.e. what some people call "realification".

(For a proof sketch, see my answer to [On a simple real Lie algebra whose complexification is not simple](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4158558/96384), for a more detailed proof in the case of far more general field extensions see my answer to [Do endomorphisms of the adjoint representation of a Lie algebra commute?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3931489/96384). To my knowledge, at least the general case is due to N. Jacobson.)

And conversely, each complex simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$, when considered as a real Lie algebra $Res_{\mathbb C|\mathbb R} \mathfrak g$, [is simple](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3742748/96384) but [not absolutely simple](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3974731/96384).

So those complex-simple-viewed-as-real Lie algebras are all examples. The smallest one, the six-dimensional real $Res_{\mathbb C|\mathbb R} \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$, stands out in the sense that it [happens to be isomorphic to another "classical" Lie algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4759891/96384), namely $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$. This exceptional isomorphism, or rather, the fact that there is an exceptional second name for $Res_{\mathbb C|\mathbb R} \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$, boils down to the fact that the root system $A_1 \times A_1$ can also be called $D_2$. While for any other simple root system $R$, its product with itself $R \times R$ does not have any other name elsewhere in the list of root systems.